# Search in a python list

Tags: python, search, dictionary, comparison

I have a dynamic list like this:

```
 list = [{'Question 1': {'Job': 'job1', 'Country': 'USA', 'Car': 'Porche'}},
         {'Question 1': {'Job': 'job2', 'Country': 'UK',  'Car': 'Nissan'}},
         {'Question 3': {'Job': 'job8', 'Country': 'GR',  'Car': 'Toyota'}},
         {'Question 4': {'Job': 'job1', 'Country': 'USA', 'Car': 'Toyota'}},
         {'Question 4': {'Job': 'job5', 'Country': 'USA', 'Car': 'Toyota'}},
         {'Question 4': {'Job': 'job5', 'Country': 'USA', 'Car': 'Porche'}},
        ]
```

Every dictionary in list is a user that answered question (Question 1, Question 2, ..) and every dictionary in list dictionary is profile. I want make a search (or comparison) like this:

```
Number of users that answer the Question 4 :3
Countries : 3 From USA
Car : 2 Toyota, 1 porche
Job : 2 job5, 1 job 1
...
...
```

How can I make a comparison like this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What other (`...`) searches do you want to perform?

Comment: @Tichodroma ,  If there is other profile items. (like age, city, country) . Thanks for help.

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name. This way you hide the original `list` function.

Comment: @pkit: `list` is a type/class (depending 2k or 3k), not a function.

Comment: @nightcracker It is also listed as a built-in function http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#list

Comment: @pkit: Yes, it is callable, but it really is a type: `type(list) == type` in 2.7.2.

Comment: @nightcracker, I think there's a case to be made for thinking of a type as a function that returns an object of the type defined.

Comment: @senderle: you could call a type a factory function for objects, but in Python this is only the case because they use the same calling scheme as functions, `()`. This is not necessarily the case in all programming languages, so I like to think as a type as a separate entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we can use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

answers = [
    {'Question 1': {'Job': 'job1', 'Country': 'USA', 'Car': 'Porche'}},
    {'Question 1': {'Job': 'job2', 'Country': 'UK',  'Car': 'Nissan'}},
    {'Question 3': {'Job': 'job8', 'Country': 'GR',  'Car': 'Toyota'}},
    {'Question 4': {'Job': 'job1', 'Country': 'USA', 'Car': 'Toyota'}},
    {'Question 4': {'Job': 'job5', 'Country': 'USA', 'Car': 'Toyota'}},
    {'Question 4': {'Job': 'job5', 'Country': 'USA', 'Car': 'Porche'}},
]

counted = Counter([item for q in answers for answer in q.values() for item in answer.items()])
```

I have renamed `list` to `answers` to avoid confusion with the `list()` builtin.

The `Counter` counts individual items in a list, so what we do here is use a list comprehension to extract the individual items from your list - as the questions don't seem to matter, given your examples, and then use the counter to count them. Note that this is quite a complex list comprehension as your data structure is a little awkward, you may want to consider changing it. This then returns:

```
Counter({
    ('Country', 'USA'): 4, 
    ('Car', 'Toyota'): 3, 
    ('Job', 'job5'): 2, 
    ('Job', 'job1'): 2, 
    ('Car', 'Porche'): 2, 
    ('Job', 'job8'): 1, 
    ('Job', 'job2'): 1, 
    ('Country', 'UK'): 1, 
    ('Car', 'Nissan'): 1, 
    ('Country', 'GR'): 1
})
```

If you wanted to select individual things, you can do, for example:

```
countries =  [(key, value) for (key, value) in counted.items() if key[0] == "Country"]
```

Which gives us:

```
[
    (('Country', 'UK'), 1),
    (('Country', 'GR'), 1), 
    (('Country', 'USA'), 4)
]
```

If you needed to count the number of users answering a said question, simply change the focus of the counter by changing what the list comprehension picks out, e.g:

```
countedQuestions = Counter([question for q in answers for question in q])
```

Which gives us:

```
Counter({
    'Question 4': 3, 
    'Question 1': 2, 
    'Question 3': 1
})
```

And the `Counter` objects are `dict`-like, so you can use them as you would a `dict`:

```
print("Number of users that answer Question 4:", countedQuestions['Question 4'])
Number of users that answer Question 4: 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Without using a different data structure, your best bet is to use a list comprehension, or some related construct, to filter the list. (And by the way, "list dict" makes no sense. Do you mean "dict list" or "list of dicts"?) Also don't use `list` as a variable name; it masks a built-in function.

```
>>> l = [{'Question 1': {'Job': 'job1', 'Country': 'USA', 'Car': 'Porche'}},
...      {'Question 1': {'Job': 'job2', 'Country': 'UK',  'Car': 'Nissan'}},
...      {'Question 3': {'Job': 'job8', 'Country': 'GR',  'Car': 'Toyota'}},
...      {'Question 4': {'Job': 'job1', 'Country': 'USA', 'Car': 'Toyota'}},
...      {'Question 4': {'Job': 'job5', 'Country': 'USA', 'Car': 'Toyota'}},
...      {'Question 4': {'Job': 'job5', 'Country': 'USA', 'Car': 'Porche'}},
...     ]
>>> [d for d in l if 'Question 1' in d]
[{'Question 1': {'Country': 'USA', 'Job': 'job1', 'Car': 'Porche'}}, 
 {'Question 1': {'Country': 'UK', 'Job': 'job2', 'Car': 'Nissan'}}]
```

For getting counts only, you could do something like this to avoid creating a new list:

```
>>> sum('Question 1' in d for d in l)
2
```